# Navigating from admin site to one of my apps in same project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to the Django and i am stuck on one of the major issues.I want to move to my app lets say "Student". I want that user click on a Link and simply moves from admin site to one of the apps.
Thanks in advance any kind of help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a method in your model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return "An url computed with resolve() for example"
```

A button will appear on top right of the admin side.

Example

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return resolve('home_page')
```

will send you to the page named (in `urls.py`) 'home_page'.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

[EDIT]

This is not well documented in the django documentation. You have to search in the Django source tree.

First create a template with this path (assuming `templates` is your templates default root directory):

`templates/admin/index.html`

Which contains:

```
{%extends 'admin/base_site.html'%}
{%block content%}
<style>
    a.btn { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; line-height: 50px; }
</style>
<div><a href="/admin/app1/model1/" class="btn">Your first app with the model1</a></div>
<div><a href="/admin/app1/model2/" class="btn">Your first app with the model2</a></div>
<div><a href="/admin/app2/model/" class="btn">Your second app with a model</a></div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is a very basic sample and it will completly override the standard presentation. You can add buttons with a little bit of CSS.

To add a entry you can add:

```
<div><a href="/admin/app1/model1/add/">Add a new entry in app1/model1</a></div>
```

All the Django admin templates are in this path. It can be very helpful to understand it :

`[DJANGO_ROOT]/contrib/admin/templates/`

I think it's what you want.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply i followed your directions but its still not working.No button is displayed 
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return resolve('myapp.views.list')

Comment: So I didn't understand your question. Did you mean : From the admin root page you want go to this app or the other ? If yes, let me know, I wrote something like that on day. But you should consider django-admin-tools in that case or write your own admin panel (the hard way).

Comment: i want to move from admin root to my app or the other way will work too..I dont want to build the admin panel hard way